# Showing that something is a sufficient statistic

Tags: statistics

I tried to do the following task:

> Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be a random sample with the pdf
>
> $$f_{X_i}(x|\theta)=\begin{cases}e^{i\theta-x},&&x\ge i\theta\\0,&&x<i\theta\end{cases}$$
>
> Show that $T=\min_i \frac{X_i}{i}$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$.

First of all, I don't know what the notation $f_{X_i}(x|\theta)$ should mean.

Does it mean that $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n|\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}e^{i\theta-x_i}1_{x_i\ge i\theta ,\forall i \in\{1,\ldots,n)\}}$?

(I plan to use the factorization theorem)

Comment: notation $f_{X_i}(x | \theta)$ is just a notation saying that $x$ is an argument and $\theta$ is a parameter. The likelihood function is written correctly. Go for factorization theorem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write 
\begin{align}
f(X_1, \dots, X_n ~|~ \theta) &= \prod_{i=1}^n e^{i\theta - X_i} \mathbf{1}_{X_i \ge i \theta} \\
&= \exp\left\{\theta \frac{n(n+1)}{2} - \sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right\}\mathbf{1}_{\min_i \frac{X_i} i \ge \theta} \\ 
&= \exp\left(-\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right) \left[\exp\left\{\frac{\theta n (n + 1)} 2\right\} \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\min_i \frac{X_i} i \ge \theta}\right].
\end{align}
So, the first exponent doesn't depend on $\theta$, while the second term depends on $\theta$ and the statistics used in second exponent is exactly $\min_i \frac{X_i} i$. Hence, $T(X) = \min_i \frac{X_i} i$ is indeed a sufficient statistics.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly how my solution would have turned out. Except one thing: shouldn't the indicator functions be outside of $\exp\{\}$?

Comment: you are completely right, I'll edit my answer shortly.